# Export birthdays from facebook (Redesigned Events Page)

Tags: facebook

Before you guys start tormenting me by saying that it's a repeated question, my question deals with the redesigned Facebook events page, even at Facebook help if i check how to export birthdays, the help text given there is for the old page, wherein it says that you need to click the "magnifying glass" icon, from there select birthdays and so on. But the redesigned events page doesn't have this option.

I'm really getting annoyed since even Facebook didn't change its help text. There is no option to select Birthdays or export birthdays.

Comment: Yes. There is no button for it. So strange